# How to add a UNION clause between two SQL statements in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$sql_new=$sql1. UNION .$sql2;
```

This expression gives the following error notice:

> Use of undefined constant UNION - assumed 'UNION' in php

Comment: Can we get some more delete votes on this question please? It is good it was solved, but I don't think it has any long-term value for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql_new=$sql1 . " UNION " . $sql2;
```

you have to put your strings into quotes so that PHP knows it's a string.